# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #170: Error inflating class fragment

Tags: android, google-maps, listview, android-fragments, google-maps-api-3

Activity crashes after i add google maps API in my manifest file.I have added a map fragment in another fragment in Activity but if i add API the file crashes .Please help.here is my full error-

```
     android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #170: Error inflating class fragment
                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:767)
                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:810)
                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813)
                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813)
                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:508)
                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:418)
                                                                    at com.gjs.placesjson.BookFragment.onCreateView(BookFragment.java:90) //THis is view Inflate
                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2080)
                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1108)
                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1290)
                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:801)
                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:1638)
                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:679)
                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:143)
                                                                    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1240)
                                                                    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1088)
                                                                    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1614)
                                                                    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17562)
                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5536)
                                                                    at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:700)
                                                                    at android.support.design.widget.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:90)
                                                                    at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(AppBarLayout.java:1364)
                                                                    at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:765)
                                                                    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17562)
                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5536)
                                                                    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
                                                                    at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
                                                                    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17562)
                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5536)
                                                                    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
                                                                    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
                                                                    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
                                                                    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17562)
                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5536)
                                                                    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
                                                                    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17562)
                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5536)
                                                                    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
```

here is layout where the problem is shown line 170

```
      <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        tools:context=".MapsActivity"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_width="340dp" />
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: paste your layout file of BookFragment.

Comment: Please check again i have added the layout

Answer (score 0):

have you add this library :

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.1'
```

then rebuild the project.